# Why is the given space not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X =\mathbb R^2 - \{0,0\}$, let $\mathbb Z$ act on it by $n(x,y) = (2^nx, y/2^n)$, and denote the quotient space by $X/Z$. Show that $X/Z$ is not Hausdorff. I think that the only problematic point would be$(0,0)$, which we exclude in this case. Can anyone give me any hint on this one?

Can anyone solve this question? I do not really know where to start.

Comment: Are you sure that's the formula you want? Because it's not an action as written...

Comment: I am sorry that I missed an x

Comment: Can you find a sequence that has two limit points?

Comment: I can try to find one but why would this contradict with it being Hausdorff? @arkeet

Comment: Because in any Hausdorff space, any sequence converges to at most one point.

Comment: Hint: I'm thinking of a sequence $(a_n)$ in $X$ (which happens to not converge), such that the sequences $(n \cdot a_n)$ and $(-n \cdot a_n)$ converge to different points in $X$.

Comment: Consider $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant, it goes to $(\infty, 0)$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, and goes to $(0,\infty)$ as $n$ goes to $-\infty$. This sequence in some sense has two limits, but I still cannot get a contradiction.@arkeet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46094/discussion-between-koch-and-arkeet).